# Error: Command "start" is not available outside of a Sanity project context

Tags: sanity

Run the command again within a Sanity project directory, where "@sanity/core"
is installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sanity start` command needs to be run inside the folder with Sanity installed so it knows what Sanity instance to start up.

You need to navigate into that folder (should be the one with `sanity.json` in it) and then run `sanity start` again.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate into your Sanity folder and run `npm i` which would install your dependencies, including the Sanity package. Then run `start`.